# Mariadb init script

Tags: init, mariadb

I installed MAriadb form sources on debian.
I used the init script mysql.server.

I have that error when run it :
`Starting MySQL

.Manager of pid-file quit without updating file. ... failed!`

There is no mysqld.pid anywhere, there is no mysqld executed.

.err file : 

`110209 17:04:55 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

110209 17:04:55 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'

110209 17:04:55 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to 
create it.

110209 17:04:55 [Note] PrimeBase XT (PBXT) Engine 1.0.11-7 Pre-GA loaded...

110209 17:04:55 [Note] Paul McCullagh, PrimeBase Technologies GmbH, 
http://www.primebase.org

InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4

110209 17:04:55  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.

110209 17:04:55 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 1.0.13-11.6 started; log sequence number 45356

110209 17:04:55 [ERROR] Aborting



110209 17:04:55  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...

110209 17:04:55  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 45356

110209 17:04:55 [Note] PrimeBase XT Engine shutdown...

110209 17:04:55 [Note]

110209 17:04:55 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended`

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a debian package with normally will work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This normaly means that you've just upgraded to a new version but the tables haven't been upgraded yet. Start mysql with --skip-networking and --skip-grant-tables. Then run mysql_upgrade. Now stop and restart the mysql server without those extra options.